# I have a SQl Insertion Error In My Library Mangement Project. I tried to Figure out myself but failedd many times.Help me out

Tags: java, mysql, database

```
String sql="insert into return (Student_ID,S_Name,F_Name,Course,Branch,Year,Semester,Book_ID,B_Name,Edition,Publisher,Price,Pages,Date_Of_Issue,Date_Of_Return) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
```

Error Says:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'return values-->

```
stm=con.prepareStatement(sql);
stm.setString(1,jTextField1.getText());
stm.setString(2,jTextField2.getText());
stm.setString(3,jTextField3.getText());
stm.setString(4,jTextField4.getText());
stm.setString(5,jTextField5.getText());
stm.setString(6,jTextField6.getText());
stm.setString(7,jTextField7.getText());
stm.setString(8,jTextField8.getText());
stm.setString(9,jTextField9.getText());
stm.setString(10,jTextField10.getText());
stm.setString(11,jTextField11.getText());
stm.setString(12,jTextField12.getText());
stm.setString(13,jTextField13.getText());
stm.setString(14,jTextField14.getText());
stm.setString(15, ((JTextField)jDateChooser1.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText());
stm.execute();
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Book Returned");
}
catch(Exception e)
{
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
```

Comment: `return` is a reserved word so use `\`return`\`

Comment: better solution in my opinion is to rename return to something else and do not use reserved words as table name.

Answer (score 0):

First rename the "return" table in something else, it will prevent you about many error that can occur in the database or into java. Return is a reserved keyword in many cases.

In order to execute an insert you should use the stmt.executeUpdate() function.

Furthermore you should use named parameters to ensure each parameter is what it should be.

Comment: Thanks for the Help Mate :-)